# How to remove white broad border from Shinobi Pie Chart?

Tags: android, charts, shinobi

[image]

I have been trying to implement Shinobi Pie Chart, everything working fine but I can't remove this white broad border from the pie series(Please refer the image attachment).

I have tried something like 
     style.setCrustShown(false);(but it removes the thin separator line, not what I actually want to be removed).

```
Please, post the appropriate method to remove that border.
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

```
PieSeriesStyle style = series.getStyle();

style.setChartEffect(RadialEffect.FLAT);// does the trick
```